# Write a function to get customers, just pass the addressid and read all it's customers? parameter (addressId)

Tags: javascript

**Javascript**
As You can see my javascript code Im trying to get customers based on the address id. I'm struggling to get customers based on the address.

```
var customers = [
    { id: 1, name: "Customer1", email: "customer1@test.com", addresses: [1, 5, 3, 10] },
    { id: 2, name: "Customer2", email: "customer2@test.com", addresses: [2, 8, 10] },
    { id: 3, name: "Customer3", email: "customer3@test.com", addresses: [5, 2] },
    { id: 4, name: "Customer4", email: "customer4@test.com", addresses: [3, 7, 8] },
    { id: 5, name: "Customer5", email: "customer5@test.com", addresses: [4, 6, 9] },
];
var addresses = [
    { id: 1, street: "Riche street", city: "TPT", pin: "232434" },
    { id: 2, street: "Cross street", city: "Vellore", pin: "75646456" },
    { id: 3, street: "Colony", city: "Chennai", pin: "7887878" },
    { id: 4, street: "Annai Nagar", city: "Bangalore", pin: "43545" },
    { id: 5, street: "Main Bazar", city: "Salem", pin: "4567767" },
    { id: 6, street: "Gandhi Nagar", city: "Hosur", pin: "232434" },
    { id: 7, street: "Gandhi Nagar", city: "Pondicherry", pin: "75646456" },
    { id: 8, street: "Colony", city: "Krishanagiri", pin: "7887878" },
    { id: 9, street: "Annai Nagar", city: "Ambur", pin: "43545" },
    { id: 10, street: "Main Bazar", city: "Vaniyambadi", pin: "4567767" },
];

function getCustomers(get_id) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
        if (get_id == addresses[i].id) {
            console.log(addresses[i].id);
            for (var prop in customers) {
                if (customers.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    if (
                        prop.addresses.filter((x) => {
                            x == addresses[i].id;
                        })
                    ) {
                        console.log(prop);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

getCustomers(10);
```

I thing I missing something here...
If I pass 10 as as parameter it will fetch the customer records who are belongs to addresses 10.

Output well be:

```
 { id: 1, name: "Customer1", email: "customer1@test.com", addresses: [1,5,3,10] },
 { id: 2, name: "Customer2", email: "customer2@test.com", addresses: [2,8,10] },
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that returns a list of customers based on the address ID passed:

```
function getCustomers(addressId) {
  return customers.filter(customer => {
    return customer.addresses.includes(addressId);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You Go

```
let obj = [
 { id: 1, name: "Customer1", email: "customer1@test.com", addresses: [1,5,3,10] },
 { id: 2, name: "Customer2", email: "customer2@test.com", addresses: [2,8,10] },
 { id: 3, name: "Customer2", email: "customer2@test.com", addresses: [2,8,5] },
 { id: 5, name: "Customer2", email: "customer2@test.com", addresses: [6, 8, 9] },
]

function getCustomers(data, id) { //data will be your object from which to find id
    let customers = [];
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.addresses.forEach(function(a) {
            if (a == id) {
                customers.push(d);
            }
        });
    });
    return customers;
}
```

**note: this function will return you values as array of objects**